# Is there a general representation of $u[n-a]-u[n-b]$ in terms of unit impulses $\delta$?

Tags: convolution

Consider in the discrete-time domain, the unit-step function :
$$
u[n]=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $n\geq 0$}\\
0&\text{if $n<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
We know that the first-order difference equation describes a relation between the unit-impulse function and the unit-step function as follow :
$$
\delta[n]=u[n]-u[n-1]
$$
I was wondering that in general, how can we express a difference equation of this kind :
$$
u[n-a]-u[n-b]
$$
In terms of unit impulses $\delta$? With $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$

Comment: Is $ a-b$ an integer? If so, you can chain together $\delta[n] + \delta[n-1] + \ldots$.

Comment: Hello, yes I have fixed the question, can you clarify more?

Comment: Can you write out what $ \delta[n] + \delta[n-1]$ is? How about $ \delta[n] + \delta[n-1] + \delta[n-2]$? Do you see a pattern? Now, express $u[n-a] - u[n-b]$ in terms of these $\delta[n-i]$.

Comment: So it appears that $\displaystyle u[n]-u[n-b]=\sum_{k=0}^{b}\delta[n-k]$ so this means $\displaystyle u[n-a]-u[n-b]=\sum_{k=0}^{a}\delta[n-k]-\sum_{k=0}^{b}\delta[n-k]$ Can we improve this sum? @CalvinLin

Comment: So I assume this should give us $\displaystyle\sum_{k=a}^{b}\delta[n-k]$ assuming $a<b$ right?

Answer (score 1):

$u(x)=\int\limits\limits_{-\infty}^x\delta(x)\,dx$ where $u(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and $\delta(x)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

So $u(x-a)-u(x-b)=\int\limits\limits_{-\infty}^x(\delta(x-a)-\delta(x-b))\,dx$